# Gradient matrix of loss function for single hidden layer neural network

Tags: partial-derivative, matrix-equations, gradient-descent, neural-networks

so I have a function $$\hat y=f(x)=\mathbf{w}_2^\mathsf{T}\pi(\mathbf z)$$

with $$\mathbf z=\mathbf W_1^\mathsf T\mathbf x$$ and $$\pi(x)={1\over1+e^{-x}}$$. As  squared loss we use  $$l={1\over 2}(y-\hat y)^2$$

now I want to find the gradient matrix of $l$ with respect to $\mathbf W_1$

I found a good [article](https://sebastianraschka.com/faq/docs/backprop-arbitrary.html) that helped my understand how to tackle the problem. Therefore I use the Chain rule and I came up with:
$${\partial l \over \partial\mathbf W_1}={\partial l \over \partial\hat y}{\partial \hat y \over \partial\pi}{\partial \pi \over \partial\mathbf z}{\partial \mathbf z \over \partial\mathbf W_1}$$

The first part should be $(y-\hat y)$

the second part $\mathbf w_2^\mathsf T$

and the third the derivative of sigmoid $\pi(\mathbf z)(1-\pi(\mathbf z))$

now I can't come up with the derivative for z with respect to W.
Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by taking the differential of the loss function,

then successively substitute the various variable definitions.
$$\eqalign{
{\cal L} &= \tfrac{1}{2}(\hat y-y)^T(\hat y-y) \\
d{\cal L}
 &= (\hat y-y)^Td\hat y \\
 &= (\hat y-y)^TW_2^Td\pi \\
 &= (\hat y-y)^TW_2^T(P-P^2)\,dz \\
 &= (\hat y-y)^TW_2^T(P-P^2)\,dW_1\,x \\
}$$
where the matrix $P={\rm Diag}(\pi)$.

Since a scalar expression is equal to its trace, i.e.
$$y^TAx = {\rm Tr}(y^TAx) = {\rm Tr}(xy^TA)$$
we can rewrite the differential as
$$\eqalign{
d{\cal L}={\rm Tr}\Big(x(\hat y-y)^TW_2^T(P-P^2)\,dW_1\Big)
}$$
from which the gradient [can be identified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Identities_in_differential_form) as
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial{\cal L}}{\partial W_1} &= (P-P^2)W_2(\hat y-y)x^T \\
}$$
or the transpose of this,
depending on your preferred [layout convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Layout_conventions)

As you've discovered, the difficulty using the chain rule in matrix calculus is that it *often* requires the calculation of intermediate quantities which are higher-order tensors, e.g. matrix-by-matrix, matrix-by-vector, or vector-by-matrix derivatives.

The differential approach is simpler because the differential of a matrix behaves like an ordinary matrix. In particular, it obeys all of the rules of matrix algebra.